# クイックソートと同時にランキングを作ることはできますか？

Tags: アルゴリズム

```
A,10,50,32
B,30,60,21
C,15,45,61
```

というcsvファイルを読み込んで、A~Cの順番を崩さずに次の条件を満たしたdat、csvファイルを出力したいです。順番を崩したくない理由は、A, B, Cの並び順によって一意な値（配列の添え字）を割り振るためです。

- 降順にソートした結果の4列目のデータだけのdatファイル
  期待する出力：

  ```
  61
  32
  21
  ```
- 5列目に4列目のデータで降順ソートした時のランキング順位
  期待する出力：

  ```
  A,10,50,32,2
  B,30,60,21,3
  C,15,45,61,1
  ```

またソートには平均計算時間が早いクイックソートを使いたいです。

---

現在はどうやって実装するかを考えている段階で、配列に3列目だけを代入してクイックソートを実施して、順位付けは別でfor文などを使って実現しようと考えていました。

しかしせっかくクイックソートで順位とほぼ等しい降順データが取れているのに順位付けのために別途繰り返し構文を書くことが非効率に思えてしまい、何か方法がないかと悩んでいます。

クイックソートとランキング順位付けを同時に実行することは可能ですか？あるいはソートアルゴリズムを変更すれば可能でしょうか？

以上の点についてご教授よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 例えば python の pandas パッケージには [pandas.DataFrame.rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) があって、簡便にランキングデータを取得できます。`df['ranking'] = df[3].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)`

Comment: 昇順というのは、一番小さいものから、一番大きいものへの順で、上からに並べるのが一般的だと思います。
質問の、"昇順にソートした結果の3列目のデータだけのdatファイルの
期待する出力："では、一番大きい 61 から始まって、一番小さい 21 が最後（一番下)になっています。
質問者が使っている「昇順」の定義を明確にして頂けませんか？

Comment: @Fumu7 コメントありがとうございます。昇順と降順を混同していました。修正しました。

Comment: 列の先頭の A, B, C が何を表していて (本来ならここが1列目では？)、ここを基準に行の並びを維持しなければいけないのはなぜなのでしょうか？ / より重要そうに見えるランキング順位を基準に並び替えてしまうのも一つの考え方なのかなと思いました。

Comment: @cubick A, B, Cの並び順によって一意な値（配列の添え字）を割り振るためです。なので、元の並び順を維持しないと入出力時で割り振る値が変わってしまいます。/列番号の件、ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正しました。

Comment: @cubick かきそびれましたが、ふたつ目の理由に入出力で行の順序が同じだと結果を見比べやすいと感じた点もあります。

Answer (score 4):

> 順位付けのために別途繰り返し構文を書くことが非効率に思えてしまい、

順位付けを別処理にすることは非効率とは思えません。

クイックソートの平均計算量は O(n log n)、最悪で O(n^2) ですが、その後の順位付けは O(n) で済みます。
また、ソート中に順位を確定するのは難しいです。実装したとしても順位確定判定用のIF文を毎回通すことになり、かえって非効率になってしまうと思います。効率を求めるのであれば、繰り返しの回数よりも条件分岐の回数に注意したほうがよいと思います。
どうしてもソートと順位付けを同じ処理で行いたい場合はバブルソートであれば簡単に実装すればできそうですが、確実に遅くなるのでやはりおすすめしません。
さらに、複数の機能を１つの処理にしてしまうというのはおすすめできません。メンテナンスのしやすさを考えると機能単位で処理がまとまっていたほうがわかりやすいかと思います。

参考として、私がC#で実装するとしたら以下のようなコードになります。4列目の値をキーにリストそのものをソートして新しいリストを作成しています。

```cs
public class Data
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Value1 {get; set;}
    public int Value2 {get; set;}
    public int Value3 {get; set;}
    public int Rank {get; set;} // 入力CVSを読み込んだ時点ではRankは未定
}

public void Sample(List<Data> source)
{
    // Value3でソートしたリストを作る。
    // sourceとrankingは並び順が異なるだけで、要素のデータは同じものを参照している
    List<Data> ranking = source.OrderByDescending(e => e.Value3).ToList();

    // 順位付け。Value3が同値だった場合の対応は未実装です
    int rank = 1;
    foreach(var data in ranking)
    {
        data.Rank = rank;
        rank++;
    }

    // 出力：Value3
    foreach(var data in ranking)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{data.Value3}");
    }

    // 出力：ランクを付加したデータ
    foreach(var data in source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{data.Name},{data.Value1},{data.Value2},{data.Value3},{data.Rank}");
    }
}
```